# How to write an onclick function for a dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have some buttons that look [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5CQ.png)

It is a "whitelist" of websites. I'd like for the button to remove the corresponding site from the whitelist.

However, since these buttons are generated with each addition of a site (entered by the user), I don't know how to get the ElementID to use in my function.

Here is where the button is generated:

```
  var cellWebsite = document.createElement("td");
  var website = document.createTextNode(array[i]);

  //append cell text to cell, then cell to row (like setting a "stage")
  cellWebsite.appendChild(website);
  row.appendChild(cellWebsite);

  //create a cell & cell text for BUTTON
  var cellDelete = document.createElement("td");
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //has its own element
  var text = document.createTextNode("x");
  button.appendChild(text);
  cellDelete.appendChild(button);
  row.appendChild(cellDelete);
```

How do I get the ID so I can write a function for when the X button is clicked? Within that function, how can I get the website that corresponds to that button?

I'm making a Chrome Extension and using chrome's local storage, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an event listener the button variable like so:

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = "Click me!";
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('Fired!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to comment since I need 50 rep. for it, but can't you give it an increment? With each add just increment the ID or name with 1, and then u could target the ID or name.

Comment: Interesting! How would one increment the ID? Or even set it?

Comment: I am no pro, so don't value me too much in this thread, but you could use a function in javascript/jquery, assign an ID to it or name (whatever u want) for example: Name: 'MyButtonName['+ ButtonIncrement +']' (and set MyButtonName to 0). Each time a button is made it will assign an increment to it and store it in ur local-storage (I used JSON for what I was doing and would target my name that way). you basically need to reproduce the function u wrote for one button. Yet again, I am no pro either in javascript. Just trying to give my input from what I know. So don't value what I say too much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inspection view of your browser and see if id and other attributes are set.

If this didn't work, make use of the form id attribute the index of the element as፡
var x = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;

If no id provided for form:

var x = document.forms[0].id;
Or
var x = document.forms.item(0).id;

Answer (score 0):

When your element is dynamically created, You should event delegation to handle event.

Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent.  That event listener analyzes bubbled events to find a match on child elements.

**Example:**

```js
var counter = -1;

function addRow() {
    counter++;

    var table = document.getElementById( 'myTable' ),
        row = table.insertRow( counter ),
        cell = row.insertCell( 0 ),
        cellDelete = row.insertCell( 1 ),
        button = document.createElement( 'button' ),
        text = document.createTextNode( 'X' );

    cell.innerHTML = 'wikipedia.org ' + counter;
    button.appendChild( text );
    cellDelete.appendChild( button );

    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
        table.deleteRow( e.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex );
        counter--
    } )
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}
table {
    width: 100%
}
td {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
}
td:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: right
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #efefef
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add new row</button>
<br>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```